# Полупрозрачный фон поверх картинки при наведении курсора

Tags: html, css, css3

Имеется код галереи на css3 для одностраничного сайта. Три картинки в три ряда. При нажатии картинка увеличивается поверх остальных картинок. 
Всё работает хорошо, но. Мне нужно что бы при наведении на картинку она покрывалась голубым полупрозрачным фоном с текстом, а уже после при нажатии разворачивалась. Но это у меня ни как не выходит реализовать. P.S. Вроде бы правильно оформил.

```css
 /*Убираем рамку фокуса*/
 :focus {
   outline: none;
 }
 /*Основной блок*/
 .gallery {
   width: 980px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   position: relative;
 }
 /*ссылки-контейнеры*/
 .gallery a {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 10px;
   display: inline-block;
   height: 130px;
   position: relative;
   width: 300px;
 }
 /*картинки внутри ссылок*/
 .gallery a img {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 10px;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: block;
   left: 0px;
   width: 300px;
   height: 130px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 10px;
   z-index: 1;
 }
 /*ссылка получает фокус и картинка разворачивается*/
 .gallery a:focus img {
   border: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: 2px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);
   border-radius: 3px;
   cursor: default;
   height: 300%;
   width: 300%;
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 25;
   transition-duration: 0.7s;
 }
 /*положение каждой развёрнутой картинки*/
 .gallery a:focus:nth-child(3n+1) img {
   left: 0;
   top: -145px;
 }
 .gallery a:focus:nth-child(3n+2) img {
   left: -315px;
   top: -145px;
 }
 .gallery a:focus:nth-child(3n+3) img {
   left: -640px;
   top: -145px;
 }
 .gallery a:focus:nth-child(-n+3) img {
   top: 10px;
 }
 .gallery a:focus:nth-child(n+7) img {
   top: -300px;
 }
 .gallery a:focus:nth-child(n+10) img {
   top: -300px;
 }
 /*кнопка закрытия и сброса фокуса*/
 .closed {
   background-color: rgb(250, 75, 21);
   position: absolute;
   top: -5px;
   right: 20px;
   display: none;
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   cursor: pointer;
   z-index: 30;
 }
 /*текст внутри кнопки закрытия*/
 .closed p {
   margin: 10px 8px;
   font-size: 10px;
   color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   position: absolute;
 }
 /*прозрачный блок поверх развёрнутой картинки для закрытия*/
 .closed-layer {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   top: 100px;
   left: 100px;
   width: 800px;
   height: 400px;
   background: transparent;
   z-index: 30;
 }
 /*блоки закрытия получают фокус*/
 a:focus~.closed,
 a:focus~.closed-layer {
   display: block;
   transition-duration: 4s;
 }
```

```html
<div id="bottom">
  <div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="gallery">
      <a tabindex="1">
        <img src="image/nor1.jpg">
      </a>
      <a tabindex="1">
        <img src="image/nor2.jpg">
      </a>
      <a tabindex="1">
        <img src="image/nor3.jpg">
      </a>
      <a tabindex="1">
        <img src="image/nor4.jpg">
      </a>
      <a tabindex="1">
        <img src="image/nor5.jpg">
      </a>
      <a tabindex="1">
        <img src="image/nor6.jpg">
      </a>
      <a tabindex="1">
        <img src="image/nor7.jpg">
      </a>
      <a tabindex="1">
        <img src="image/nor8.jpg">
      </a>
      <a tabindex="1">
        <img src="image/nor9.jpg">
      </a>
      <span class="closed"><p><i class="icon-cancel"></i></p></span>
      <span class="closed-layer"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная цель, создать или создавать в каждом блоке с картинкой (**теге A**), с `position: relative;` перекрывающие элементы (**полупрозрачный голубой фон** и **текстовый элемент**) с `position: absolute`, и растянуть их на весь **тег A**. Можно текстовый элемент создать в самом блоке с голубым полупрозрачным фоном, но в таком случае, придётся мириться с влиянием полупрозрачности на текст. Изначально, перекрывающие элементы должны быть скрыты, а при срабатывании ***события*** **hover** на **теге A** - должны отображаться

Примерная реализация на чистом **CSS** ([**Живой пример**](https://jsfiddle.net/HA3IK/t7bnyftu/)):

```
/* Ссылки и обёртка для картинок (тег A) */
.img-link {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 130px;
}

/* Общие стили для перекрывающих элементов */
.cover-bg,
.cover-title {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

/* Отображаем перекрывающие элементы при наведении на блок с картинкой */
.img-link:hover .cover-bg,
.img-link:hover .cover-title{
  display: block;
}

/* Полупрозрачный перекрывающий голубой фон */
.cover-bg {
  background: #77c4f0;
  -khtml-opacity: .6;
    -moz-opacity: .6;
         opacity: .6;
}

/* Перекрывающий текст */
.cover-title {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 120%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Ну а с помощью **JS**, можно вставлять все нужные элементы перекрытия, при наведении, и приплести сюда нужные эффекты

Comment: Это оказалось настолько просто, что мне стыдно. А ведь просидел над ним пол дня.. Спасибо вам огромное.

Answer (score 0):

Как пример
https://jsfiddle.net/apvdctg3/

далее оформить текст, сменить цвет overlay